# how to integrate flask app to the wordpress

Tags: wordpress, flask, integration

I have embedded an AI Chatbot (using Python)in a flask application Now I want to add this application to my Wordpress website . Is there a possible way to integrate the application in Wordpress.

I tried to create a plugin but I couldn't convert the Flask application to a plugin in Wordpress

What I expected : A way to add the flask app(Chatbot) to my Wordpress website